# Regex in node.js to find a match in a XML

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a below XML file

```
<configs>
    <config environment="DEV">
        <URL>http://www.devurl.com</URL>
    </config>
    <config environment="SIT">
        <URL>http://www.siturl.com</URL>
    </config>
    <config environment="UAT">
        <URL>http://www.uaturl.com</URL>
    </config>
    <config environment="PROD">
        <URL>http://www.produrl.com</URL>
    </config>
</configs>
```

and am trying to write a regex to find the URL value that is configured for PROD environment. Below is my sample Regex

```
 var regexp = /<config environment="PROD">[^]*?<\/config>/gi;
 var matches_array = data.match(regexp);
 console.log(matches_array[0]);
```

which returns

```
<config environment="PROD">
    <URL>http://www.produrl.com</URL>
</config>
```

as a result, but i expect my regex should return URL tag alone as a result for eg :

```
<URL>http://www.produrl.com</URL> or http://www.produrl.com
```

Can any one help me to get this work.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: You'd be better off with an XML parser.... https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-parser

Comment: I think this is technically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/(?=config environment="PROD").*\s*<URL>([^<]*)<\/URL>/gm
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0hSII5/2)**

I took the prod environment config and extracted the url from it:

- `(?=config environment="PROD")` is a **Positive Lookahead** that checks that we are in the **PROD** environment configuration
- `.*\s*<URL>`...`<\/URL>` just takes care that we are taking the URL from inside the **URL** tags
- `([^<]*)` here we have a `Capturing Group` that extracts the URL.

I hope this helped